# Using a callback to consume data from std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++

Based on the previous answers, I wrote a better buffer that can be consumed fast:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Buffer
{
public:

    Buffer(size_t reserve) {
        _buffer.reserve(reserve);
    }

    void write(T* buffer, size_t amountToWrite) {
        this->_buffer.insert(this->_buffer.begin(), buffer, buffer + amountToWrite);
    }

    size_t consume(const size_t amountToConsume, std::function<void(T*, T*)> onConsume) {
        if (_current==this->_buffer.size()) {
        //this means we've already read everything. Maybe we should throw or just return 0?
        return 0; 
        }

        size_t currentActualSize = this->_buffer.size() - this->_current;
        if (amountToConsume <= currentActualSize) {
            onConsume(this->_buffer.data() + this->_current, this->_buffer.data() + this->_current + amountToConsume);
            this->_current += amountToConsume;
            return amountToConsume;
        } else {
            size_t remaining = currentActualSize;
            onConsume(this->_buffer.data() + this->_current, this->_buffer.data() + this->_current + remaining);
            this->_current += remaining;
            return remaining;
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _buffer;
    size_t _current = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Buffer<uint8_t> b(7);
    uint8_t u[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    b.write(u, 7);

    uint8_t r[3] = {255, 255, 255};
    
    size_t consumedBytes2 = b.consume(3, [r](const uint8_t* begin, const uint8_t* end){
        std::cout << "begin: " << begin << ", end: " << end << std::endl;
        std::copy(begin, end, (uint8_t*)r);
    });
    
    std::cout << "consumed " << consumedBytes2 << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<consumedBytes2; i++) {
        std::cout << (int) r[i] << " - ";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and I added a callback that calls with the buffer begin and end, so I can write to whenever I want, instead of copying to a temporary buffer and then writing to another buffer.

However, as you can see, the output is:

```
begin: , end:                                                                                                                                                         
consumed 3                                                                                                                                                            
255 - 255 - 255 -
```

nothing is being written to my buffer.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are capturing your array by value.

Capturing by reference will give you the expected result.

```
size_t consumedBytes2 = b.consume(3, [&r](const uint8_t* begin, const uint8_t* end){
    std::cout << "begin: " << begin << ", end: " << end << std::endl;
    std::copy(begin, end, (uint8_t*)r);
});
```

Capturing a pointer by value would have worked fine, but the array doesn't decay to a pointer here as it would when passed to a function.

Comment: what is the type of an array if not a pointet?

Comment: It's type is `uint8_t [7]` in this case.

Comment: @Gatonito Array is an array and a pointer is a pointer. Array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.

Comment: You could capture a pointer: `[uint8_t * p = r]`